# Crashing after couple of hundred frames rendered

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

Blender crashing after some hundred or lesser frames gets rendered.
I have to re-open file, re-touch frames range and keep on rendering!

Fixes I experienced before and did on this file and failed:

- Checked subdivision levels and lowered them all. (did well on render time but still crashin!)
- Checked camera clip range, which I faced in other projects, when it's clip end is too large, it makes a lot of ram to use and causes crashes. (not worked)
  *Checked if there is very large textures exists (almost all are procedural), no!

specs: intel-corei7-7700, 16gb ram, GTX1060 6gb, SSD, Window 10, everything is updated

[Here is the Log file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1p1TQ6mHnRAzC59Zuq5Lpys5n5cCIKcC9/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Hard to tell remotely, but are you rendering into a shared directory, like Dropbox?
Also: untick overwrite, you don't have to adjust the framerange everytime

Comment: No, the folder is a separate one, not shared anywhere, and hey, thanks for the hint on Overwrite thing, really appreciate!

Comment: I don't see a way to PM you. Can you find me on BlenderDiplom.com? I am working on a render helper that restarts Blender on crash and tries to finish the animation. I could give you the beta version, so you could help me test it. So far it's windows only, but I am porting it to linux and mac as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is gone by updating to 3.4.1!
I had problem in all kind of rendering workflows: crash to desktop in Compositor, Sequencer and Scene itself!
Now it all gone... seems like the stability is raised a lot in this version, also rendering time increased (I use EEVEE in this project).